# scheduling sketches in a gallery show

Tags: processing

I'm curating a gallery show for Processing student works, so I've got ~100 sketches I want to cycle through about 10 iMacs over time.

I can export the sketches, run them through the IDE, or through the `processing-java` tool. I'm really keen to have a seamless transition from one sketch to the next (perhaps with a fade-to-black transition). If necessary, I can even make sure that the sketches all include certain code/hooks to assist.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** Do this from Processing.

You could create a giant Processing sketch that uses the `millis()` function to determine how much time has gone by, and then calls the correct drawing code from the student sketches. You'd probably have to edit the student sketches to make sure the variable names and functions don't clash. This is the simplest option, but it might require a lot of manual work to make the student sketches compatible.

**Option 2:** Do this from Java.

This is probably the option I would go with.

You could export the student sketches as Java applications, then import the resulting `.java` files into a new Java project. That Java application could simply call `PApplet.runSketch()` to run each student sketch. Something like this, maybe with a little more code for transitioning:

```
for(PApplet studentSketch : studentSketches){
   PApplet.runSketch(studentSketch new String[]{"StudentSketchTitle"});
   waitTenMinutes();
   studentSketch.exit();
}
```

**Option 3:** Do this from a shell script.

I'm less knowledgeable about shell scripting, but the basic idea is the same: you'd write a shell script that runs the sketches and then waits a certain amount of time. This isn't any different from scheduling any other application, and there are probably a ton of resources on Google for this approach. You'd probably have to write the transition code into the sketches themselves though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I agree that option 2 looks the best - I might even write a little clojure tool to do it. I know that the [applet stuff](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0#things-that-may-break-your-2x-sketches) has changed in Processing 3.0, but I'll have a look at the docs.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`, so you can't embed it as a component like you used to. You could try going back to Processing 2 if you need that, but the better option is to use the `runSketch()` function, which does pretty much what it says on the box.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kevin Workman. Just one more question - is exporting the sketches the best way to get a PApplet from each sketch (i.e. from a bunch of .pde files in a folder)? Or can I call `PApplet.main()` with the path to the folder directly?